# Using tree view in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have added a tree view to my form. I want to capture the values of checkboxes, which one is checked or not.

Also I am trying to get the count of nodes. There are four nodes in the tree,

```
Dim nodes As TreeNodeCollection = TreeView1.Nodes
    MsgBox(nodes.Count)
```

gives 1.

Thanks

Comment: [Here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/treeview) is a good tutorial, although in C# you should be able to easily apply it to VB.

Comment: You probably have 1 root node with 4 child nodes.  Use TreeView1.Nodes.Nodes instead.

Comment: I've created functions like this before - Do you need the list of checked nodes or just the count of how many are checked??

Comment: John please tell me how to get the list of checked nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... This probably isn't the best way to do this, but it works...

The function would look something as follows:

```
Function GetAllCheckedNodes(ByVal tv As TreeView, Optional ByRef tn As TreeNode = Nothing) As List(Of TreeNode)
    Dim RetVal As New List(Of TreeNode)


    If tn Is Nothing Then
        For Each nd In tv.Nodes
            RetVal.AddRange(GetAllCheckedNodes(tv, nd))
        Next
    Else

        If tn.Checked Then RetVal.Add(tn)

        For Each nd In tn.Nodes
            RetVal.AddRange(GetAllCheckedNodes(tv, nd))
        Next
    End If

    Return RetVal
End Function
```

And your code to use it would look something like:

```
    Dim MyList As List(Of TreeNode) = GetAllCheckedNodes(tvAccounts)
```

or

```
    Dim MyList As List(Of TreeNode) = GetAllCheckedNodes(tvAccounts, nd)
```

Where `nd` is a specific node in the treeview where you want to get all the children nodes that are checked.

Hope this helps and makes sense.